# How to properly setup dynamic library loading with header file?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

The title was tough to get right, so let me explain my situation:

Another team develops a library. They ship a header file and a `*.so` file. The header file is available to us, and we can include it in our own code and use it if we wish. The `*.so`, however, is shipped with the platform we run on. We do not have access to this `*.so` at build time for our software. Because of this, we can't really use the header file either, since the linker will expect the `*.so` to be available at some point.

Right now what I do is create a wrapper class that loads the `*.so` file at runtime, then uses `dlsym()` to find functions by name, and I map them to function pointers.

Is this the only option? Is there a way I can use the header file but tell the linker to not resolve the symbols at build time, but instead try to resolve them at runtime after we have a chance to load the `*.so` file?

Note the real platform here is Android (via NDK), but hoping general linux advice will work as well in this case since we have POSIX APIs available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, in order of preference:

1. Get the libraries from the maintainer. Providing the header but not the library (at least a stub library like we do for libraries in the NDK) just won't work.
2. Build your own stub library. It's pretty straightforward if you have a list of symbols to expose. Put `int foo; void bar() {}` in a C file for all the variables and functions you need to expose and build it as a shared lib. If you have the list of symbols in a version script, you might be able to use Android's [gen_stub_libs.py](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/master/cc/gen_stub_libs.py) to do it for you.
3. Mark all the symbols with `__attribute__((weak))` in the header file. The linker won't complain that they are missing. If they're missing at runtime, the library will still load but each function's address will be `nullptr`. Not really what you want in most cases because if your definition of the library is wrong, you turn build time failures into runtime failures, but in some cases this can be handy because it's easier to check for function availability with `if (foo) { foo(); }` then to do similar with `dlsym`.
4. Add `-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined` to your ldflags. This is even worse than 3 because it affects all the libraries you link, but it wouldn't require you to meddle with the header.

Comment: I like #1 the most, the downside is that now I have to make sure I get the latest library every time they release a new version, as opposed to "automatically" getting it with the firmware releases on the device.

Comment: Ideally they'd provide it to you alongside the headers.

Comment: What I mean is, most of the time the public interface doesn't change, just the implementation. So should I upgrade it regardless or somehow know which releases create an ABI incompatibility and upgrade only those?

Comment: As long as the ABI doesn't change, you don't need to update the stubs. Fetching the updated ones every time will protect you from surprises if it does change though.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows this is solved by requiring export library (.lib) to be present for linker instead of real dynamic library (.dll). I think you can try making something similar, that is making a fake .so containing stubs of all the methods exported from real .so and linking against it. This hopefully will make linker happy and at the same time at runtime application will load real .so.

Comment: This is what the NDK does with the platform libraries, FWIW.